# Active MQ -> Connection resumed listener not called when initially active mq service is down and i restart the service

Tags: c#, jms, activemq-classic

Consider the following scenario, I am using SSL transport layer to connect to Active MQ.
Say initially the activemq service is down.

An exception listener is called but when i up or restart the service the connection the ConnectionResumedListener is not called.

But everything works fine when the very first time activemq is up and running, the connection interrupted listener and connection resumed listener gets called perfectly.

Can anyone help how to handle the case where the activemq service is down the very first time, how do i know when the service is up and started ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear whether you are using failover but let's assume you are.  In the case where the connection cannot be established because the broker is not running when you start your app the client will always pause on Connection.start() until such time as the connection is made.  There will be no connection resumed event because the connection was never interrupted, the events interrupted and resumed always occur in that order.